# Selenium: how to get the entire html as a string?

Tags: python, selenium

I am using Selenium with python. See the following code:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import selenium.webdriver
driver = selenium.webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=APP")
```

Now, I want to do one simple thing: get the html of that web as a string from the `driver`. Then, I can use `BeautifulSoup` to parse it. Does anyone know this?

Actually, I don't how to access information from this `driver`, e.g., to get the stock price of apple in this case.

I am totally new to Selenium. A good tutorial for it is highly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you're using Selenium for this? If you only want to extract html for use with `BeautifulSoup`then it is almost certainly overkill and you should use something like `requests`

Comment: The reason is that the web to be scraped is implemented with infinite scroll. I want to use the driver to scroll down to the bottom of the web again and again to gradually crawl all the data in that web. I know this is computationally inefficient. But I do not have better solution now. Do you have any better suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for [page_source](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.page_source).

To continue along with your example:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source)
```

As another commenter noted however, you could use a library like [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) to the same effect:

```
r = requests.get('http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=APP')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)
```

Comment: AThe reason is that the website I want to scrape is implemented with infinite scroll. I want to use the driver to scroll down to the bottom again and again in order to scrape all the data. Is this too computationally costly or even impossible? If so, do you have any good suggestion to tackle the infinite scroll?

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at following code.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import selenium.webdriver
driver = selenium.webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=APP")
page_html = driver.page_source
```

In page_html you will have html of opened page.